# Polynomials: $f(x) = (x-1) g(x)$, $f(x) = ax^(n+1) + bx^n + 1$. Find explicit form of $g(x)$.

Tags: polynomials

Let $a, b ∈ \Bbb R$  and $n ∈ \Bbb N\,,\,\, n ≥ 1$ . $f(x) = ax^{n+1} + bx^n + 1$ .

(a) Find a necessary and sufficient condition on $a$ and $b$ s.t. $1$ is a root of $f(x)$.

(b) Explicitly give the polynomial $g(x)$ s.t. $f(x) = (x-1) g(x)$.

(c) Under which condition will $1$ also be a root of $g(x)$?

---

I've answered (a) by saying that if $1$ is a root of $f$, then there exists a polynomial $g(x)$ of degree $n$ s.t. $f(x) = (x-1) g(x)$.

However, I am stuck on (b). I thought that perhaps doing long division on $p(x)$ would give me a neat answer but ended up with a strange $f(x) = (ax^n + (b+a) ∑_{i=1}^{n-1}x^i + (b + a))$ + some kind of a remainder $(b+a+1)$ -- not a polynomial. I think I may have the wrong idea of what I am supposed to do.

Would like hints in order to solve (b) and (c).

Comment: Your "answer" to (a) is not such: what are those conditions on the parameters $\,a,b\,$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't done with (a), yet. $1$ is a root of $f(x)$ if and only if $0=f(1)=a+b+1.$ Thus, we have our necessary and sufficient condition on $a$ and $b$.

For (b), writing $b=-a-1$, we have $$f(x)=ax^{n+1}-(a+1)x^n+1=ax^n(x-1)-(x^n-1)=(x-1)\left(ax^n-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k\right),$$ giving us $g(x)$.

For (c), note that $g(x)$ has $1$ as a root if and only if $f(x)$ has $1$ as a multiple root, if and only if $f'(x)$ has $1$ as a root. I leave that to you--think about how we did part (a).

Comment: I understand now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$x^n-1 = (x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+ \cdots + x + 1)$$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$(a)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;0=f(1)=a+b+1 \ldots$$

$$(b)\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{long division}\ldots$$

$$(c)\;\;\;\;\;\text{A polynomial has a multiple root $\,w\,$ iff also its derivative vanishes at $\,w\,$}$$

Comment: Thanks for edit and hints.